# Woocommerce hide pricing for unregistered customer

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hide, hidden-field

I'm trying to set up my woocommerce shop to hide prices to logged out users. I have two different codes that each only to a part of what I want.

This code hides the price but when they click a variant it still shows the add to cart button and they can see the price in the cart:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html','members_only_price');
function members_only_price($price){
if(is_user_logged_in() ){
return $price;
}
else return '<a href="' .get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('myaccount')).         
'">Login</a> or <a href="'.site_url('/wp-login.php?   
action=register&redirect_to=' .         
get_permalink()).'">Register</a> to see price!';
}
```

This bit of code hides the add to cart and price, but doesn't show the color options/variations:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html','members_only_price');
function members_only_price($price){
if(is_user_logged_in() ){
return $price;
}
else .remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item',   
'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' ).remove_action( 
'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 
).remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 
'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 ).remove_action( 
'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 
10 );
}
```

this is a link to the product page: http://69.195.124.58/~creatfs4/?product=wood

My PHP coding skills are novice... I keep trying to add bits here and there but it doesn't work.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I recently had the same question and I got a working answer, give it a look! 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45263249/4843705