# Hide product prices and add-to-cart buttons but not variations for unregistered users in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

In my WooCommerce shop I want to hide the prices until the customer has logged in. I've got the following code working that does exactly that:

```
add_action('init','hide_price');
function hide_price(){
    if(!is_user_logged_in()){
        remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart',10);
        remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart',30);
        remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_price',10);
        remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_price',10);
        add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','print_login_to_see',31);
        add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','print_login_to_see',11);
    }
}

function print_login_to_see(){
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('myaccount')) . '">' . __('Login to see prices','theme_name') . '</a>';
}
```

However this also removes the variation drop down and I would like to keep that.

Is there any direct way to keep the variation drop down menu but still hide the prices until the customer has logged in?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:**

You will need to separate shop and archives pages from single product pages. In single product pages you will target variable products to add and remove the specific hooked functions.

Last thing, in your function **`print_login_to_see()`**, **`woocommerce_get_page_id()`** is obsolete and it's replaced by **`wc_get_page_id()`** …

So your code will look to this:

```
// For product archives pages
add_action( 'init', 'hide_product_archives_prices' );
function hide_product_archives_prices(){
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) return;

    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10) ;
    add_action ( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'print_login_to_see', 10 );
}

//
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'hide_single_product_prices', 1 );
function hide_single_product_prices(){
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) return;

    global $product;

    remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );

    if( ! $product->is_type('variable') ){
        remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary','print_login_to_see', 30 );
    } else {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation', 10);
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'print_login_to_see', 20 );
    }
}

// Display a my account link 
function print_login_to_see(){
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) ) . '" class="button">' . __('Login to see prices','theme_name') . '</a>';
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested on WooCommerce 3+ and works.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply Loic, once again! However I'm still running WooCommerce 2.6 so I assume the "obsolete" and deprecated functions are still required for my installation here, this as the code above doesn't directly function as it still shows the prices for not logged in users.

So my best guess is that some functions that are deprecated in newer versions, are still required for the older 2.6 version?

Either way thanks!

Comment: @RafaëlDeJongh You can try to keep `wc_get_page_id`… If it doesn't work use the deprecated one… I am going to test this on WooCommerce 2.6.x and I come back to you with the correct answer…

Comment: Seems it wasn't a problem with the deprecated function, rather the return; after the if statement. If this were just default {} then it worked. So the code of yours works when the if( is_user_logged_in() ) return; is switches with if( is_user_logged_in() ){ //other code here }

Working perfectly now so thanks once again Loic!

Comment: @RafaëlDeJongh When I have been testing, sorry I have forget to remove the `!` in the `if( ! is_user_logged_in() ) return;` … So now is ok, I have corrected it :)

Comment: @RafaëlDeJongh … In the shop and archives pages, you should have replace the add-to-cart button by your button for the simple products, and keep the "select options" button for variable products …

Comment: Yep that did it as well! Thanks again for the great support and fast replies!